# How to use nth-child() but not for child in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am looking to do something similar to jQuery's eq() selector to target elements on a page based on their order. :nth-child() is exactly what I need except I want to target elements are are not children. For example:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

If I wanted to target the 2nd div above, what can I use in css (without actually giving it an id or class)?

Comment: Your example is pretty poor because both `div`s are children of an implicit `body`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pick the nth element out of a set of arbitrary, unrelated matches with CSS selectors.

You can only do this in jQuery using `$('div:eq(1)')`.

Comment: Ooo `nth-match` ... interesting. Have an upboat.

Comment: @Russell: I have a dreadful feeling that I should be keeping CSS4 stuff under wraps instead of dropping hints like this here and there :S

Comment: @Russell: I reviewed the CSS4 spec, and it doesn't seem that `:nth-match()` will do the same thing as jQuery's `:eq()` because `:nth-match()` behaves like `:nth-child()` in that it limits itself to sibling elements :/ Here's the link again: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#nth-match

Answer (score 0):

If those are the only to adjacent div elements, then you could use `div + div`. Otherwise that would match all divs starting from the 2nd one.

In that case, you'd also have to reset whatever CSS you've applied by specifying an `div + div + div` rule. That would apply to all following divs starting from the 3rd.